# parametrized methods in controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i am new in spring. I have following controllers:

1) Simple controller that adds party to database.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/party")
@SessionAttributes()
public class PartyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newPartyGet(@ModelAttribute("party")
        Party party, BindingResult result) throws IOException{
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/views/party/party_add.jsp", "party", party);
        return mav;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newPartyPost(@ModelAttribute("party") Party party,
        HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException{
        if (party.validate()) {
            //here is called servlet, which add party to google app engine database
            return "forward:/partyadd";
        } else {
            party.fromRequest(req);
            return "/views/party/party_add.jsp";
        }
    }
```

2) Same, but with contests.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/party/{id}/contest")
@SessionAttributes()
public class ContestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newContestGet(@ModelAttribute("contest")
        Contest contest, BindingResult result) throws IOException{
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/views/contest/contest_add.jsp", "contest", contest);
        return mav;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newContestPost(@ModelAttribute("contest") Contest contest,
        HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException{
        if (contest.validate()) {
            //here is called servlet, which add contest to google app engine database
            return "forward:/contestadd";
        } else {
            party.fromRequest(req);
            return "/views/contest/contest_add.jsp";
        }
    }
```

And few more, to add probes or participants.

Difference between these controllers isn't noticeable, so I want to write one controller with two methods which allow me to serve this forms.

Is it possible?

Ok, i see that i didn't explain too good what i want to say.

i have a lot controllers, all look like this:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes()
public class MyObjectController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView MyObjectGet(@ModelAttribute("myObject")
        MyObject myObject, BindingResult result) throws IOException{
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/views/myObject_add.jsp", "myObject", myObject);
        return mav;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String MyObjectPost(@ModelAttribute("myObject") MyObject myObject,
        HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException{
        if (myObject.validate()) {
            //here is called servlet, which add myObject to google app engine database
            return "forward:/myObjectadd";
        } else {
            myObject.fromRequest(req);
            return "/views/myObject_add.jsp";
        }
    }
```

where 'myObject' can be contest, participant and more. Normally i could repeat this code a lot times for all things, but i think there is better solution.

Comment: Cant understand your question.... can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you just have to use a common `@RequestMapping("/party")` on controller class then your methods from ContestController have to be as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/contest/new", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/contest/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```